# Run While loop in the background

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a javascript application Angular based that runs a while loop after a  user press a button it runs the loop until we get a certain number then the loop ends. currently am not able to do anything else on the UI when the loop is running is there a way to push this loop to the background so the user can continue other things on the UI.

Comment: You might want to look at web workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded.  You can't have a loop run while the UI remains useful, unless you use a web worker.

Comment: Definitely a web worker case.

Answer (score 2):

Use angular watchers for that:

```
$rootscope.watch(myParam, function () {});
```

Or use non-blocking `setInterval()`:

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (myParam == 'what-i-need') {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use webworker, as sample code below (the code is not fully functional but it just to give you an idea.

```
(
function () {
    var scope = self;
    var condition = false

    scope.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        var caller = event.data;
        if(caller.name && caller.command && caller.command === 'TERMINATE'){
            return;
        }              
        start(caller);
    }, false);

    function start(){
        while (condition) {
            if(condition)
                scope.postMessage({result:"result"});                

        }
    }

})();
```

In your angularjs controller or service

```
if (!worker) {
                    worker = new $window.Worker("./online-capability-worker.js");
                    worker.addEventListener('message', onResponse, false);
                }
function onResponse(event) {
            var response = event.data;
            //This is my nuber returned by worker
        }
```

Comment: Didn't realize few ones already suggested web workers - Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is synchronous, while event driven systems allow it to mimic an asynchronous language, your code is still running on a single thread. You could use a setTimeout to recursively call a function rather than use the while loop, that way there is time for the thread to do other things in between each iteration.

```
function incrementNumber(initial, destination){
    if(initial < destination){
        setTimeout(function(){incrementNumber(initial+1, destination}), 10);
    }else{
        alert('We found the number!');
    }
}
```

I would like to point out that I agree with the use of setInterval for something as simple as changing a number, but in browsers (to the best of my knowledge still), the interval is kicked off from the time the callback is initially called, which can cause unexpected results if the callback itself has any significant execution time (say, an ajax call).